# resx localization in mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, localization

I have three resource files in App_GlobalResources for a view:

```
ConditionsLabels.en.resx
ConditionsLabels.ua.resx
ConditionsLabels.ru.resx
```

But I can't get any value. 
I specified custom namespaces (ViewRes), but in the view autocomplete suggests the only variant `@ViewRes.ConditionsLabels_ua`. (it's class)

How can I use that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `App_GlobalResources` for MVC projects.  Instead, place your .resx files in a standard folder (say, "Resources" or whatever).  Next, select the .resx files in Visual Studio and change the following properties:

```
Custom Tool: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
Custom Tool Namespace: Resources
```

Now you should be able to access your resources normally using `Resources.MyResource.String1`, etc.

Comment: I used it, but result is the same. It suggests only *Resources.ConditionsLabels_ua* class, from where I can access strings. I can't access *_en* and *_ru*

Comment: @user1760300 do you have the file `ConditionsLabels.resx`, with all the string keys?  That's needed as the base file.

Comment: Aw, so I need one with default language? I changed  name `ConditionsLabels.en.resx` to `ConditionsLabels.resx`, and now can access it values from the view too, but not the russian version

Comment: @pink.fascist normally you don't access the Russian version directly... set the Current Culture to `ru-ru` and then `Resources.ConditionsLabels.String1` will give the Russian text...